# app.auth is not a function after upgrade to angular8

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, angular8

I've recently upgraded my `Angular` project to version 8, but I'm struggling to upgrade `angularfire2` to version 5.2.1 which supports Angular 8. I constantly getting the error:

```
TypeError: app.auth is not a function...
```

I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall `angularfire2`. I also cleared the entire node modules folder and reinstalled all the packages.

This is what the dependencies look like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.13.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "material-bottom-nav": "^1.0.6",
    "ng": "0.0.0-rc6",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.0.1",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-deepcopy": "^0.1.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "update": "^0.7.4",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.0.3",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.126",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.30",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "firebase": "^6.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "i": "^0.3.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "ts-node": "~6.0.5",
    "tslint": "~5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
```

Did someone already upgrade to `angularfire2` version 5.2.1 and can help me out with this?

Comment: angularfire2 is an old wersion of @angular/fire

Comment: .auth() is an firebase-admin function make sure you are using it in Functions not in angular project.

Comment: Just in case You cannot use firebase-admin library in your Angular project. Use this library in Firebase Functions and remember function .auth() need to end with "()" it's an common issue.

Comment: If u want to trigger functions using Angular project u have module to do this `AngularFireFunctionsModule` U can import it to your project from @angular/fire library.

Comment: @Mises I do not import firebase-admin in the module and I also use @angular/fire as you can see in the dependencies.

Comment: I uninstalled firebase-admin and now the project runs as expected. Thank you very much! @Mises

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the firebase-admin library from the project solved the issue.

```
npm uninstall firebase-admin
```